# Facebook User Access Token PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As stated on the Facebook documentation, ***access tokens*** are portables, that means that an ***access token*** could be obtained on the **front-end side** of the application and passed to the **back-end side** to handle Graph API requests.

The problem is: how to properly instantiate and setup the Access Token in the **back-end** side?

I'm currently doing the following code:

```
use Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken;
$accessToken = new AccessToken('{access-token goes here}');
print_r($accessToken); // inspecting the token
```

When ***print_r*** is called, some of the token information are missing, such as the ***expiresAt*** attribute. This attribute, for instance, is present when the ***access token*** is generated by the **FacebookRedirectLoginHelper::getAccessToken** on the callback process.

Does the lack of this attribute interferes on the flow of things? If so, then how to properly instantiate a portable **Access Token** in the **back-end**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0#fbcallback

Sample code:

```
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks!